# No property 'findFirst' found for type Entity in spring CrudRpository

Tags: spring-data, spring-el

I want to persist a state of revenue, which is a single `BigDecimal` value that changes depending on check-ins and check-outs of activities and their prices. I began with a SQL approach, but I got an error. I'm thinking about other approaches as well.

## SQL approach

I want the table to have a single row

**Finance**

| id | revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |

in PostgreSQL and create an entity along with repository in Spring Data. The table will have a single row and will serve as a state of revenue.

Entity

```java
public class Finance {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column
    @ColumnDefault("0")
    private BigDecimal revenue;
}
```

with a repository

```java
@Repository
public interface FinanceRepository extends CrudRepository<Finance, Integer> {
    /**
     * gets the revenue from the Finance table, assuming there is only one
     *
     * @return revenue
     */
    Finance findFirst();

    /**
     * assumes that there is only one row in the Finance table
     *
     * @param finance finance with revenue set to the value to update the database to
     */
    @Query("update Finance set revenue = ?#{finance.revenue}")
    void updateRevenue(Finance finance);
}
```

but I get the error in runtime

> Caused by: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`: Failed to create query for method public abstract `Finance` `FinanceRepository.findFirst();` No property `'findFirst'` found for type `'Finance'`

I think `updateRevenue` doesn't work as well, but I'm not sure since the error about `findFirst` comes first.

I tried `@Query("select revenue from Finance where 1=1 limit 1")` on `findFirst` as well, but Spring loader complained about `limit` that it's incorrect.

Should I use top or is the only way to create my own implementation with my own SQL? Is there a way to get the unique row using SpEL?

## Other approaches

I guess NoSQL solution might be more suitable or a table like

**Finance**

| id | name | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | revenue | 0 |

with repository `Finance findFirstByName(String name)`.